# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!}$ using the Taylor series of $e^{x+2 }$.

**Answer:**

$$
e^{x+2}=1+(x+2)+\frac{(x+2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x+2)^3}{3!}+\ldots
$$

Integrating, we get
$$
\int e^{x+2} dx=x+\frac{(x+2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x+2)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x+2)^4}{4!}+\ldots
$$

Again integrating, we get

$$
\int e^{x+2} dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{(x+2)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x+2)^4}{4!}+\frac{(x+2)^5}{5!}+\ldots\\
\Rightarrow \int e^{x+2} dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+(x+2)^3 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!}\\
\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!}=\frac{\int e^{x+2} dx-\frac{x^2}{2}}{(x+2)^3}
$$

**Is this the sum of the series ?**

Comment: With undefined integral — certainly not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is sound, but you should be clear about one thing: when you write $\int e^{x+2}\,\mathrm dx$, what you mean is $\int_0^xe^{t+2}\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: I am not sure that this will make the OP realize that his result is plain wrong.

Comment: "Your approach is sound" Well, no it is not.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$

Set $n+3=m$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!}=\sum_{m=3}^\infty\dfrac{(x+2)^{m-3}}{m!}=\dfrac1{(x+2)^3}\sum_{m=3}^\infty\dfrac{(x+2)^m}{m!}$$

Now, $$\sum_{m=3}^\infty\dfrac{(x+2)^m}{m!}=e^{x+2}-\sum_{m=0}^2\dfrac{(x+2)^m}{m!}$$

Comment: look at carefully this does not give the sum of the required series. Because the given series is $ \sum \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!} \ $ while your computation gives the series $ \  \sum \frac{(x+2)^{n+3}}{(n+3)!} \ $

Comment: @yourmath, Please find the updated answer. We don't need calculus here

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for integrals.

Multiply the sum by $(x+2)^3$ to let the exponents match the denominators and add the missing initial terms to obtain an exponential:

$$1+(x+2)+\frac{(x+2)^2}2+(x+2)^3S=\sum_{n=-3}^\infty\frac{(x+2)^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}=e^{x+2}$$

from which you draw $S$ (which is not what you found).